# TYPO3 11 Sitepackage Tutorial expected template file Standard/1.html

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-11.x

**TL;DR:**

The Backend Layouts of the site package tutorial (Default/Standard and Two Columns) do not show up for new pages in Appearance -> Backend Layout. The error message in this thread (1.html) is an artefact of prior Backend Layouts which came from the original old site setup.

**Solution:**

To make the Backend Layouts of the site package tutorial show up there, I had to edit the root page of the site: Resources -> Include static Page TSconfig (from extensions) and add site-package from the Available Items list.
This can also be achieved without "Resources -> Include static Page TSconfig (from extensions)" but via file `ext_localconf.php` in the root of the site package extension (`gpcf_theme`):

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') || die();

$boot = function (string $_EXTKEY): void {
        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig('
                <INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:'.$_EXTKEY.'/Configuration/TsConfig/Page/Page.tsconfig">
        ');
};
$boot('gpcf_theme');
unset($boot);
```

**Original Question:**

I'm still trying to bring an existing (older) web page into Typo3 11 following the TYPO3 Sitepackage Tutorial.

Currently I get an

```
"Oops, an error occurred! Code: 202111161210589c32f8c0"
```

and can't get rid of it whatever I do.

The corresponding entry in the log files is (line breaks added by me):

```
../../var/log/typo3_61306f633c.log:Tue, 16 Nov 2021 12:10:58 +0000 [ALERT] request="30cc4e082c853" 
component="TYPO3.CMS.Frontend.ContentObject.Exception.ProductionExceptionHandler": 
Oops, an error occurred! Code: 202111161210589c32f8c0- InvalidTemplateResourceException:
Tried resolving a template file for controller action "Standard->1" in format ".html",
but none of the paths contained the expected template file (Standard/1.html).
The following paths were checked: 
/var/www/html/typo3_11/public/typo3conf/ext/gpcf_theme/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/, 
in file /var/www/html/typo3_11/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/View/TemplatePaths.php
```

I can't find the reason of this error, because I have no idea, where the needed template Standard/1.html is requested from.

Is this some kind of hard coded default if nothing else is found?
If this is the case, the real problem is, that my customizations to the Sitepackage Tutorial source code seems to be wrong, but it never produced any different error despite the above one, which isn't really helpful. Ok, this is speculation, because I don't know.

As you can see, the site package was renamed to gpcf_theme, it's available in the backend and applied as root template to the site. No other template is active (AFAIK). A simple newly created test page creates above error.

If I uncomment in Configuration/TypoScript/Setup/Page.typoscript the lines so that:

```
page = PAGE
page {
  typeNum = 0
  10 = TEXT
  10.value = Hello World!
}
```

same error, no hello world.

Any idea how to locate the reason for my misery?

Comment: It is exactly the same, if I use the original site_package code as extension site_package. Exactly same error. If I add a symbolic link Setup/1.html -> Default.html I get a new error: {"exception":"TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Error\\Exception: PHP Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/typo3_11/public/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/ContentObject/ContentObjectRenderer.php line 3553

Comment: I give up with this now. TYPO3 has become such a weird thing, I don't have the words for this. I am with TYPO3 since TYPO3 4.x and what it is now is just not comprehendible, the level of abstraction has increased just too high into a weirdo thing. It should be just a CMS and the system should be at least digestible for average computer experts which still have do other things in their main time. The current state (I would say since 7.x) is the most frustrating experience I ever had with all types of software systems I had contact in quite some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the fix is really simple. Try to go into the backend:

1. Edit the homepage
2. To to the "Appearance" tab
3. Set the Backend Layout for this and subpages
4. Save your change

There is a good chance that it is working now.

**Whats going on?**

You can cast this query on your database:

```sql
SELECT 
    uid, pid, title, backend_layout, backend_layout_next_level 
FROM
    pages;
```

Here you get a list of pages, some with `backend_layout` and `backend_layout_next_level` filled. Most likely your home pages has some values in this fields?

The value of this field is generated by the TSConfig for backend layouts you set in:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/11.5/en-us/ContentMapping/Index.html#dynamic-content-rendering-in-typoscript

This column is then read and processed in your TypoScript:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/11.5/en-us/TypoScriptConfiguration/Index.html#part-1-fluid-template-section

It is explained below the code snippet.

If the 4 steps from the beginning of my answer did not solve your problem, then this are the places to look.

1. In **TSConfig** is the definition of the backend layouts, columns, labels and what is written in the **pages.backend_layout** db-field
2. **DB columns** if the value makes sense `pagets__<yourTemplateName>`
3. The **TypoScript** that reads this db-field cuts of the `pagets__` takes the rest, adds `.html` and searches in the paths defined in the TypoScript below.
4. check if the **Folder and Filename of your Template file** are correct.

Comment: Thanks for this information, I think this is the right direction. I have now installed extension site-package with the original code (not my customizations), currently no changes at all. Again I get the same error, but now with 2.html (not 2.html). When I look at "Appearance" in the test page, the Backend Layouts are empty now, because I deactivated the original Backend Layout. The original Backend Layout had ID 1 (hence 1.html), during my experiments I deleted it, recreated it, and it has now the ID 2 (hence 2.html).

Comment: It's now deactivated, the site-package extension and template is activated, BUT the Backend Layouts "Default" and "TwoColumns" from the extension are not selectable, they don't show up in the drop down. This is actually a new SO question. If you like to help and think I should create a new question, let me know and I will do.

Comment: Above I wrote "2.html (not 2.html)". I meant it is now 2.html in the error log, before it was 1.html. because of the corresponding Backend Layout IDs.

Comment: Now I found the reason, why the site-package extensions Backend Layouts didn't show up in the corresponding drop downs of the page (Appearance -> Backend Layout). To make them show up there, I had to edit the root page of the site: Resources -> Include static Page TSconfig (from extensions)  and add site-package from the Available Items list. After this the extensions Backend Layouts are selectable and the original error of this thread (1.html) vanished. Why is this not part of the site-package tutorial? Or have I missed it somehow? Or is there another implicit way for this I do not know?

Comment: Ah, good to know. There are different ways how you can include `*.tsconfig`, I usually do it with `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig()` in the `ext_localconf.php` of my site packages. Inside this `tsconfig`-file you can then use the `@import 'EXT:your_ext/some/file.tsconfig'` syntax to load the rest of your tsconfig for the entire project

Comment: I think the site package tutorial is missing a crucial point here, but I am not sure if this is true, and if I were, I wouldn't be motivated to open an issue/bug either.

Comment: Added `ext_loclaconf.php` solution above.

Answer (score 0):

the error message states that the file 1.html is expected in the folder `/var/www/html/typo3_11/public/typo3conf/ext/gpcf_theme/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/`

as you noted that you have renamed the site package you may have missed some occurrences of the original package name and so some configuration is missing or pointing to nirvana.

Comment: No. It is exactly the same with the original site package code. But thanks for your answer, but you should not invest more time trying to help me. I give up with this.